# Elastic search - Unable to filter the JSON exact body using RestClient

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Trying to query the exact JSON body by using Elastic search with RestClient API, but getting the whole body as response with hits,_source,etc.

So tried the filter_path [[filter_path=hits.hits._source]] approach in order to resolve this, but even that won't help to fetch exact body and coming with _source tag as mentioned below filter_path Response.

Can any one suggest please howt to get the exact json body as response like 
{ "testAcct":"1234" }

Client.java:-

```
RestClient client = RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost(HOST, 9200, HTTP)).build();
Response response1 = client.performRequest("GET", SERVICE_URL + "_search", 
            Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(), new BasicHeader("testAcct", "1234"));
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity()));
```

Response:-

```
{  
"took":6,
"timed_out":false,
"_shards":{  
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "failed":0
},
"hits":{  
    "total":21,
    "max_score":1.0,
    "hits":[  
        {  
            "_index":"testindex",
            "_type":"testexternal",
            "_id":"AVmHwA7Pkw5MudRUOp-q",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{  
                "testAcct":"1234"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

filter_path Response:-

```
{  
"hits":{  
    "hits":[  
        {  
            "_source":{  
                "testAcct":"1234"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the way it is supposed to work, `filter_path` keeps the same response structure but weeds out any unnecessary keys you don't need/want.

Comment: Yes, exactly...